# Why generic sortBy in Kotlin not compiling?

Tags: kotlin

Why it won't compile? It tells there's some error in `list.sortBy`

```
fun <T, R : Comparable<R>> Iterable<T>.sortBy(vararg selectors: (T) -> R): List<T> {
  return this.sortedWith(compareBy(*selectors))
}

fun main() {
  class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
  val list = listOf(Person("Alex", 20))
  val sorted = list.sortBy({ it.name }, { it.age })
  println(sorted)
}
```

The error

```
Type parameter bound for R in 

fun <T, R : Comparable<R>> Iterable<T>.sortBy
(
vararg selectors: (T) → R
)
: List<T>
is not satisfied: inferred type Any is not a subtype of Comparable<Any>
```

Comment: Always post the error message. It's often the most important puzzle piece.

Comment: @Thomas thanks, updated, added error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it tries to infer the type `R` from the first lambda, it's a `Comparable<String>`. The second lambda returns an `Int` or `Comparable<Int>`, which is not a `Comparable<String>`, so it fails.

You can use star projection for the `Comparable` type since it doesn't matter if they match.

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.sortBy(vararg selectors: (T) -> Comparable<*>): List<T> {
    return this.sortedWith(compareBy(*selectors))
}
```